# Could not autowire org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSender

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I got the following problem when trying to run my application. Have debugged everything and still nothing.

The IDE is finding the bean without any issue so I'm very confused as to what is happening here.

```
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mailManager': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void com.testmail.app.service.implement.CustomMManagerService.setMailSender(org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSender); nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSender] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
```

My bean generation is located in following file:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.testmail.app")
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
 //CODE CODE CODE

    @Bean
    public JavaMailSenderImpl mailSender() {
        JavaMailSenderImpl javaMailSender = new JavaMailSenderImpl();

        javaMailSender.setProtocol("SMTP");
        javaMailSender.setHost("127.0.0.1");
        javaMailSender.setPort(25);

        return javaMailSender;
    }

// CODE CODE CODE
}
```

Code for CustomMManager:

```
public interface CustomMManager extends Serializable {
    void sendMail(String mailFrom,String mailTo,String subject,String mailBody);
}
```

Finally the code for CustomMManagerService:

```
@Service("mailManager")
public class CustomMManagerService implements CustomMManager {
    private JavaMailSender mailSender;

    @Autowired
    public void setMailSender(JavaMailSender mailSender) {
        this.mailSender = mailSender;
    }

    @Override
    public void sendMail(final String mailFrom, final String mailTo, final String subject, final String mailBody) {
        try {
            mailSender.send(new MimeMessagePreparator() {
                public void prepare(MimeMessage mimeMessage)
                        throws Exception {
                    MimeMessageHelper message = new MimeMessageHelper(mimeMessage,
                            false, "UTF-8");
                    message.setFrom(mailFrom);
                    message.addTo(mailTo);
                    message.setSubject(subject);
                    message.setText(mailBody, true);
                }
            });
        } catch (MailSendException e) {
            // your codes;
        }
    }
}
```

Help is really appreciated.

Comment: Can you try with `public JavaMailSender mailSender()`

Comment: Do the other bean declared in WebConfig work?

Comment: Are all beans under the package com.testmail.app?  Also, you say that the ide finds the bean.  Are you running this in a unit test in the ide and all works fine?  If you are running this in a webapp, how are you loading WebConfig?  Is it through xml or using WebApplicationInitializer.

Comment: public JavaMailSender mailSender() is one of first troubleshooting steps i undertook. Doesn't work. All other beans in WebConfig work fine. I use no XML everything is annotated so yes WebApplicationInitializer.

Comment: Is your code on GitHub or something?

Comment: No i have not uploaded to github. Autoinject issues i had before like this i usually forget an annotation but as you can see the base structure is all there.

Comment: Yes you are right that your code looks ok. That's way I asked about GitHub because it's not easy to figure out what is going on without the whole code

Comment: Understood, if worst comes to worst i'll recreate basic project and upload it. At this stage there are 0 interactions with this mail sender from any other sources. It is completely isolated.

Comment: Try to move your bean declaration in Root context, not in servlet context. I think that your services are declared in Root context. am I right?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As per comment from mserioli the answer is that the bean must be declared in the configuration file being called at root.

In this case:
Move

```
@Bean
    public JavaMailSenderImpl mailSender()
```

to

```
public class ExtraConfig {
@Bean
    public JavaMailSenderImpl mailSender() {
        JavaMailSenderImpl javaMailSender = new JavaMailSenderImpl();

        javaMailSender.setProtocol("SMTP");
        javaMailSender.setHost("127.0.0.1");
        javaMailSender.setPort(25);

        return javaMailSender;
    }
}
```

which is called in:

```
@Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class<?>[]{ExtraConfig.class};
    }
```

Thus solving the problem. Thanks guys for assistance.

Comment: I thought the whole point of the JavaMailSenderImpl, was that it could read the spring.mail.xxx properties. In this example, all properties are set on the JavaMailSender. Even if it works, this solution is at best confusing.

Comment: Not at all, this way you can have the Host, port and all that on a database or file or whatever. Sure you can use this config but i stumbled on this one by accident and i really needed it.

Answer (score 140):

You may have forgotten to set the following properties:

```
spring.mail.host
spring.mail.username
spring.mail.password
spring.mail.port
```

Comment: This is the cleanest solution

Comment: This works. when I compiled my app using maven it worked. However, when I ran through the IDE, it gave the error. After adding these properties the Error went away in the IDE as well!

Comment: It works. But the error message is pretty useless. It just says that the bean could not be found, but it says nothing about why, even though it should be easy to throw an error about missing parameters whenever the platform is attempting to create the bean.

Answer (score 17):

1. check application.properties config, such as:

   ```
   spring.mail.host=smtp.xxx.com
   spring.mail.username=xxx@xxx.com
   spring.mail.password=xxxxx
   spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth=true
   spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.enable=true
   spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.required=true
   ```
2. if you use spring-boot,can check should use @EnableAutoConfiguration this annotation

Answer (score 9):

to create Bean don't forgot to specify mail properties, with Java class or in application.properties file, exemple

```
# configuration email
spring.mail.host=smtp.gmail.com
spring.mail.port=587
spring.mail.username=email
spring.mail.password=password
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.enable=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.required=true
```

Answer (score 8):

As already stated you need to set at least `spring.mail.host` in your application properties. Spring Boot autoconfiguration only creates a `JavaMailSender` bean if the property is set: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/mail/MailSenderPropertiesConfiguration.java#L38

Answer (score 7):

If you use `application.yml` rather than `application.properties` for the configuartion do a double check your indentation (**structure in YAML is determined by indentation**)

In your case `mail:` should be under `spring:` like so:

```
spring:
  datasource:
    password: root
    url: jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/YOU_DATABASE?useSSL=false
    username: root
  mail:
      host: localhost
      port: 1025
      username: 
      password: 

      properties:
        mail:
          smtp:
            ssl:
              trust: "*"
            auth: true
            starttls:
              enable: true
            connectiontimeout: 5000
            timeout: 3000
            writetimeout: 5000
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to declare your bean returning the interface implemented? Something like this:

```
@Bean
public JavaMailSender mailSender() {
```

Comment: As per above comments that has been tested and it doesn't help

Comment: This should be a comment I would say.

Answer (score 1):

Configuring in *application.properties* for spring.mail related properties are good enough to do Autowire of JavaMailSender. In our case, someone also had Bean declaration and hence this was taking precedence over application.properties. Hence, Autowired was not showing. I hope this helps one.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I removed something and my project not shown as maven project.
(I am using IntelliJ for my Spring Boot application)

Set project as ***maven project*** (Close and reopen IntelliJ. It will show popup) fixes  the issue.