# a bean of type 'org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSender' that could not be found

Tags: spring-boot

I am using `spring boot 2.0.7 Release` and `spring-boot-starter-mail-2.0.7.Release.`

I am autowiring `javaMailsender` inside the class  working ok on windows while trying to deploy on `Unix` getting belwo issue

---

```
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field javaMailSender in com.fti.di.capstock.tran.pub.email.SendEmail required a bean of type 'org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSender' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
        - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSender' in your configuration.
```

---

```
    import org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSender;
    import org.springframework.mail.javamail.MimeMessageHelper;
    import org.springframework.messaging.Message;
    import org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

    import com.fti.di.capstock.tran.pub.constants.ApplicationFlowConstants;
    import com.fti.di.integration.constants.IntegrationConstants;
    import com.fti.di.integration.util.StringUtil;

    @Component("sendEmail")
    public class SendEmail {

        @Autowired
        private JavaMailSender javaMailSender;

        @Autowired
        Environment env;

        @ServiceActivator
```

Comment: Is JavaMailSender annotated with a spring annotation, like @Component? Is it inside component scanning range for Spring?

Comment: Is it necessary to make java mailsender @component . Or why its working in windows. And i followed below link https://www.mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-how-to-send-email-via-smtp/

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23246912/could-not-autowire-org-springframework-mail-javamail-javamailsender

Answer (score 12):

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSender;
import org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl;

@Configuration
public class Config {

    @Bean
    public JavaMailSender javaMailSender() {
        return new JavaMailSenderImpl();
    }

}
```

You can also return an instance of `JavaMailSenderImpl()` from your `@Bean` above  saving you the hustle of having to implement a bunch of methods when you try to return the actual `JavaMailSender()` class.

Comment: This is the right solution.

Answer (score 11):

you've to provide the mail configuration in *application.properties*

```
spring.mail.host=MAIL_SERVER_IP
spring.mail.port=MAIL_SERVER_PORT
spring.mail.userName=USER_NAME
spring.mail.password=THE_PASSWORD
```

and if authentication not enable in server then
remove userName and password and add this

```
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth=false
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.enable=false
```

Comment: also make sure this application.properties file is placed in resources folder

Answer (score 7):

Declare a @Bean of the type `JavaMailSender` in a Configuration class (This is useful when you want to inject a class which is not part of your Spring Context, like a class that belongs to a 3rd-party lib, which happens to be your case). For example:

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfig {

    @Bean
    public JavaMailSender javaMailSender() { 
          return new JavaMailSender();
    }
}
```

Make sure that the you have set the right properties under `application.properties` as well.

Also, take a look into this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23246912/could-not-autowire-org-springframework-mail-javamail-javamailsender), as I believe this is a duplicate (if it's not, I am sorry)

Comment: You may ask: Why using java config instead of just instantiating the object. Using dependency injection instead of instantiating the object makes it easier to test later. Mocking constructors forces you to use PowerMock.

Comment: Not only that. Furthermore, annotating it with @Bean makes it injectable via @Autowired and, thus, testable via Mockito, for example. Mind that `JavaMailSender` is not a class managed by the user himself but provided by Spring instead, therefore it's impossible to annotate it with @Component (this is towards the OP, @GabrielPimenta).

Comment: One other thing is that you don't want to create an instance of this class every time you need to use it. A singleton on this case is a way better approach. Also note that my example was very superficial, as, in a real world scenario, `JavaMailSender` would have been populated with its attributes before being returned.

Comment: Excellent @ThalesMinussi. You now covered all of it.

Answer (score 1):

```
In My project i was reading email properties file like hostname, port etc from spring config server (Spring cloud). 
I was missing a dependency at client end. Once i added that Dependency.

<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
</dependency>

JavamailSender class able to read those properties and worked fine.
In spring boot we need not define JavaMailSender bean manually. spring boot does itself.
```

Answer (score 1):

the best answer I ve found was to check if you have a type in your application.properties:

```
spring.mail.host
spring.mail.username
spring.mail.password
spring.mail.port
```

Check the response of **gleidson cardoso da silva** from [Could not autowire org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSender](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23246912/could-not-autowire-org-springframework-mail-javamail-javamailsender)

Answer (score 1):

This error occurred due to the missing following properties in the application.yml file.

```
  mail:
    host: localhost
    port: 1025
    username: hello
    password: hello

    properties:
      mail:
        smtp:
          ssl:
            trust: "*"
          auth: true
          starttls:
            enable: true
          connectiontimeout: 5000
          timeout: 3000
          writetimeout: 5000
```

Answer (score 0):

I have this error and it was related to missing properties in application.yml in the test folder.

Answer (score 0):

```
This message is a Spring Boot application startup error, and it occurs when the application tries to create an EmailService object but cannot find the JavaMailSender object it needs.
```

The error indicates that the program cannot find a bean of type 'org.springframework.mail.javamail.javaMailSender' in the configuration of the Spring Boot application. To solve this problem, you must define the bean that the application needs in the configuration file of Spring Boot and make sure that it is accessible.

The following code can be added in the configuration file of the Spring Boot application to define a Bean of type 'org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSender':

```
import org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSender;
import org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class EmailConfig {

    @Bean
    public JavaMailSender javaMailSender() {
        JavaMailSenderImpl mailSender = new JavaMailSenderImpl();
        // set mailSender properties (host, port, username, password, etc.)
        return mailSender;
    }
}
```

The appropriate JavaMailSender properties must be specified on the email accounts that have been used. Then the application must be restarted with the debug option enabled to view the report showing more details about the problem.